# compile error cygwin regex.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

Hello I am trying to compile the following code TextRank (Mihalcea & Tarau, 2004)
http://www.utdallas.edu/~saidul/code.html

On cygwin. When i compile I get the following error: regex.h no such file or directory. How can i add regex.h to cygwin?
And is it possible to compile on codeblock?

These are the instructions to run it:

### How to compile and run

After unzipping the code, open a shell, go to the code directory, and type the following command to compile the code.

./compile.sh

Once compiled, the code can be executed using the following command.

./TextRank paramsTextRank.txt

Comment: which compiler are you using g++, gcc, something else?

Comment: @chollida I am using GCC

Comment: I should also add that on visual studio the header is called <regex> as its a C++ compiler and they don't rely on the .h extension

Comment: @chollida Yep that's it, Thank you Chollida for your help, it worked

Comment: let's see now how can i say that the answer is correct

Comment: I've added an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the header `<regex>` instead of `<regex.h>`.  Some compilers will standardize on dropping the `.h` postfix.

Comment: Just also a small comment. I am using codeblocks to compile the code not visual studio. and GCC 4.8 for future references.